# Does ffmpeg always produce the same YUV file when decode a video file?

Tags: ffmpeg

With the same computer, same OS, and same version of ffmpeg and decoder, does ffmpeg always produce the same YUV file when decode a video file? By same I mean the YUV value is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search didn't produce any indication of non-deterministic video decoding for a `digital --> digital` signal flow.

---

In any case, you can first run :

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -flags +bitexact out1.y4m

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -flags +bitexact out2.y4m
```

And then run

```
ffmpeg -i out1.y4m -v 0 -f md5 -

ffmpeg -i out2.y4m -v 0 -f md5 -
```

Compare the MD5 values. Same here for H.264 input.